# ListItems position in the center

Tags: android, android-layout, android-actionbar, actionbarsherlock, android-dialog

I'm building my first application in android.I'm also using the ActionBarSherlock.What i want to develop now is a dialog to show with a radioGroup on top and below the radioGroup a list.I've done so, but my items on the list are positioned to the left.Is there any way i can have them positioned in the center?Thank you for your time

This is the xml:

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:orientation="vertical"
android:layout_width="match_parent" android:layout_height="match_parent">


<RadioGroup
    android:id="@+id/radiogroup"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content" >




        <RadioButton
            android:id="@+id/radioButton1"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginLeft="20dp"
            android:checked="true"
            android:text="Justified" />



        <RadioButton
            android:id="@+id/radioButton2"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginLeft="20dp"
            android:text="Unjustified" />

</RadioGroup>



<customAdapter.MyListView
    android:id="@+id/list"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_gravity="center"
    android:layout_marginTop="20dp" >

</customAdapter.MyListView>
```

and this is the actual code:

```
 public static class MyDialogFragment extends SherlockDialogFragment {
    int mNum;
    RadioButton btn1;
    RadioButton btn2;


    /**
     * Create a new instance of MyDialogFragment, providing "num"
     * as an argument.
     */
    static MyDialogFragment newInstance(int num) {
        MyDialogFragment f = new MyDialogFragment();

        // Supply num input as an argument.
        Bundle args = new Bundle();
        args.putInt("num", num);
        f.setArguments(args);

        return f;
    }

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        mNum = getArguments().getInt("num");


    }

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
            Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        View v = inflater.inflate(R.layout.myfrg, container, false);




        ListView lv = (ListView) v.findViewById(R.id.list);

        ArrayAdapter<String> dataAdapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(getActivity(), android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item,justifiedAbsences);
        dataAdapter.setDropDownViewResource(android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item); 
        lv.setAdapter(dataAdapter);






        return v;
    }
}
```

this is after i added the fravity="center"

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:orientation="vertical"
android:layout_width="match_parent" android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:gravity = "center" >


<RadioGroup
    android:id="@+id/radiogroup"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content" >




        <RadioButton
            android:id="@+id/radioButton1"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginLeft="20dp"
            android:checked="true"
            android:text="Justified" />



        <RadioButton
            android:id="@+id/radioButton2"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginLeft="20dp"
            android:text="Unjustified" />

</RadioGroup>



<ListView
    android:id="@+id/list"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_gravity="center"
    android:layout_marginTop="20dp" >

</ListView>
```

Comment: Can we have some code please !! ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to inflate your own layout to the list item. list item should look like this

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="wrap_content">  

    <!-- List item name -->
    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/name"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_centerInParent="true">
    </TextView>
</RelativeLayout>
```

Answer (score 0):

On your line

```
dataAdapter.setDropDownViewResource(android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item);
```

You should change the layout to a new one with text-centered.

Comment: you mean to create a new one?

Answer (score 0):

here is the last result..

```
<LinearLayout 
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:orientation="vertical"
android:layout_width="match_parent" 
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:gravity = "center" >

<RadioGroup
    android:id="@+id/radiogroup"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:gravity="center" >

        <RadioButton
            android:id="@+id/radioButton1"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:checked="true"
            android:text="Justified" />

        <RadioButton
            android:id="@+id/radioButton2"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="Unjustified" />

</RadioGroup>


<ListView
    android:id="@+id/list"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_gravity="center"
    android:layout_marginTop="20dp" >

</ListView>
```

Comment: what layout is it? relative? frame?

Comment: or if you want to do it in LinearLayout.. add this.. android:gravity = "center"

Comment: add this to you RadioGroup.. android:gravity="center"

Comment: what margins have to do with the centralization?

Comment: remove this from radio buttons.. android:layout_marginLeft="20dp"

Comment: yes i understood what you told me i've done so nothing.But the group was centered